# heroku run rake db:migrate: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task

I'm new in Rails and i'm trying to upload my first rails app to Heroku.

I already have my app in Heroku, but when I try to create the database I get this error:

```
vagrant@rails-forge:~/apps/betsman$ heroku run rake db:migrate --app betsman
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.3809
: No such file or directory
```

This really doesn't tell me anything though.
So I checked the Heroku logs, and get the following error:

**: No such file or directory00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby**

```
vagrant@rails-forge:~/apps/betsman$ heroku logs
2014-06-17T02:23:23.680853+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by personal_email
2014-06-17T02:23:23.680979+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by personal_email
2014-06-17T02:25:22.844616+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `echo $RAILS_ENV` by personal_email
2014-06-17T02:38:43.002052+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CRIMSON resource by personal_email
2014-06-17T02:38:43+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
: No such file or directory00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby
2014-06-17T02:38:49.957936+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-06-17T02:38:49.957154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-06-17T02:38:49.938918+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-06-17T02:38:47.948496+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 17686 -e production`
: No such file or directory00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby
```

This is my Gemfile:

```
ruby '2.1.0'

gem 'pg'
gem 'rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
#gem 'sass-rails', github: 'rails/sass-rails', branch: :master
#gem 'sprockets-rails', github: 'rails/sprockets-rails', branch: '2-1-stable'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
# gem 'bootstrap-sass'
# gem 'flat-ui-sass', github: 'wingrunr21/flat-ui-sass'
gem 'devise'
gem 'pundit'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.1.0.rc1'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'active_model_serializers', github:'rails-api/active_model_serializers' , branch: 'master'
gem 'various', '~> 0.0.2'
gem 'modernizr-rails'
gem 'bower-rails', '~> 0.7.2'
gem 'draper'
gem 'smart_listing'
gem 'cocoon'
# gem 'active_interaction'
gem 'virtus'
gem 'devise_invitable'
gem 'figaro'

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller', platforms: [:mri_21]
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'rails_layout'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'awesome_print'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  gem 'pry-rescue'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>= 3.0.0.beta2'
  gem 'faker'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.6.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'thin'
end
```

Im using Ruby 2.1.0 with Rails 4.1.1.
Any help will be welcome. Please let me know if you need something else.

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've found the solution. Apparently I had to update the files located at bin folder with this command:

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found the solution. Apparently i had to update the files located at bin folder with this command

```
rake rails:update:bin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get your database tables created, I believe the command is

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app NAME_OF_APP
```

Comment: sorry my bad... i forgot to type db:migrate... Still tho im getting the same error. I'll edit my queestion.