# Rails 5 App on Heroku db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have several Rails 4 Apps running on Heroku without problems. My newest App is written with Rails 5 and I am facing problems when deploying on Heroku. On my local machine I don't have any problems.

I deployed my app and want to `run heroku run rake db:migrate`

What I get is:

> Running rake db:migrate on ⬢ XXX... up, run.3627 (Free) : No such file
>   or directory

I also tried heroku `run rake db:migrate --app XXX` with the same problem.

The database has been created. but the migrations don't work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think in rails 5 they changed rake to rails. Try and and run "heroku run rails db:migrate"

Comment: Tried it already without success. In Rails 5 both ways should work.

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer: [heroku run rake db:migrate: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24255510/heroku-run-rake-dbmigrate-no-such-file-or-directory) you have to update your bin:

`rake rails:update:bin`

but rails 5 seems to have changed that command:

```
 rails app:update:bin
```

You can read about it here: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/14/rails-5-supports-rake-commands-using-rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 now uses `rails` as the command to run the migrations.

`rake db:migrate` is now `rails db:migrate`